# can a dog give consent?

Tags: ethics, consciousness, metaethics, animals

We know consciousness requires a specific level of awareness. Many people view other life forms who have a lower level of awareness as having a lower level of consciousness. Thus consciousness correlates on a reasonable level with awareness.

Can a dog give consent?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "consent"?  I can argue this either way, depending on that.

Comment: One option would be "moral consent", an analogy to the human notion of "consent".

Comment: Ref for prank article about dog park "rape culture": https://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2018/11/11/intellectual-dark-web-quillette-claire-lehmann-221917

Comment: To what? Are you feeding it? Having sex with it?

Comment: While this question stimulatingly prompts us to think about the nature of consent, it also concerns the nature of a non-human animal consciousness, that of a dog, and so falls within zoology. There are zoologists on this site who can use their scientific knowledge but the question is only partly philosophical.

Comment: Migrate / duplicate to law?

Comment: What is "consent"?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the Op's profile, Ric clearly knows dogs, and therefore already clearly knows the answer to his own question — yes, dogs clearly possess the requisite awareness/consciousness/whatever for "consent". No need to grossly over-intellectualize it.

What's really, really clear is that dogs can express enthusiasm, and conversely reluctance. Consent is maybe a bit more subtle, but it's not a question of if the dog can express it, but of whether or not you know the dog well enough to read its expression and body language. I've been in plenty of dog situations where it's clearly communicating, "Yeah, yeah, okay, but it ain't my first choice."

How do I know for sure that's what the dog's feeling/communicating? Well, there's the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test for intelligence, whereby Turing pretty much gave up on a quantitative definition/test for "human intelligence/consciousness". And I'd imagine we're pretty much barking up the same tree (sorry, couldn't resist) for "dog consent". And they most unquestionably pass my Turing test for that.

Answer (score 1):

According to Planned Parenthood, consent must be FRIES:

> Free, Reversible, Informed, Enthusiastic, and Specific.
>
> https://www.plannedparenthood.org/learn/teens/sex/all-about-consent

I suppose that any of these aspects of behavior could apply to dogs, except for "Free".  In many cases, it seems to me that a submissive dog has not arrived at submission without the threat of violence, or perhaps real violence.

Also, in the case of sex, it is not generally Reversible for the dog not to get pregnant once the dog has gotten pregnant.

It is hard to know if a dog knows what will happen after it has sex, so I suppose that Informed consent is also hard for a dog to grant.

Dog consent may be Enthusiastic or not.  Clearly this is a matter of circumstances.

Comment: I do not personally agree with Planned Parenthood's formulation of consent as a general definition: consent that is reversible is hard to explain and borders (to me) on incoherence.

Comment: To be self-regulating and a bit pedantic: a good way to say that consent is reversible is to prevent a language difference or misunderstanding from resulting in _rape_ on the possibility that somebody "gets consent" from somebody else and then turns his or her ears off (or enters an altered state of consciousness) and fails to provide his or her sexual partner the opportunity to demure from that moment onward.  This would be bad, but I think requiring consent to be _specific_ resolves this conflict.

Comment: A bad way to say that consent is reversible is if two people are entering into a joint business venture, in which one person makes the first big investment and the other person makes the next big investment... if the second person to invest exercises the supposed right to _reverse his or her consent_, then the first person's consent has been materially compromised because it was offered with an expectation that had not been met; i.e. the first investor's consent has been shown not to have been _informed_.

Comment: I posit that this tension between informed consent and reversible consent (which I laid out in the comment starting with "a bad way") makes the FRIES formulation of consent somewhat unstable; I wouldn't use this formulation myself and I hope that Planned Parenthood can develop something more bulletproof to tell teenagers in the future.

Comment: Are you saying once you agree to anything, you can't change your mind?

Comment: @CriglCragl, no.  I am saying that communicating your plan to do something, in a way that causes another person to make an investment, causes an obligation to arise with you: you are somehow responsible for the investment made by the other person.

Comment: One strange consequence of the FRIES formulation for sexual consent is that prostitution is plainly non-consensual, by virtue of its not being _free_.  Is this a misunderstanding of the word "free"?

Comment: @CriglCragl, the nature of investment is non-reversible change.  Consent is our system for preventing investment when a person hasn't taken full account (to his or her informed satisfaction) of the nature of this non-reversible change.  Following the non-reversible change, it is _impossible_ to reverse the change.  But it is certainly possible to change course and stop any further investment.

Comment: Your analogy seems deeply flawed. Sex is not like investing.  Imposing guilt or coercion for some next thing based on some previous thing is exactly not consent. I don't know why you would expect Planned Parenthood to approve of prostitution. In most jurisdictions it is illegal, or at most decriminalised.

Comment: @CriglCragl, imposing guilt or coercion for some next thing based on some previously agreed-upon thing is the nature of contract, of course.  I posit that consent defines the agreement by which people enter into contract.  This is not to say that sex is a contract, but that contract might be a useful analogy for sex.

Comment: @CriglCragl, in the case of consensual sex, it may not be that "a proper sequence" causes guilt or obligation to appear, but clearly the model of consensual sex _avoids_ the guilt or obligation that would appear in the avoided case.  I don't think these concepts are flawed in the way that you said; but it's true that they appear as things to avoid rather than things to create, as with business plans for investment.

Comment: You don't understand the concept of concent. And for some reason want to demonstrate that through lots of comments.

Comment: Would "revokable" be a better word than "reversible"?

Comment: @DavidThornley, it seems to me that "revokable" and "reversible" have a sort of similar function... maybe what's going on is that PP realized that for consent to be specific, people need to be reminded that it's limited in duration and doesn't create a license.  If I were writing this, I would be inclined to be more radical; rather than saying consent is reversible, I would suggest saying that consent doesn't hold very long at all: you need to get consent frequently.

Answer (score 0):

A "dog" cannot give consent in the same way a tree cannot. While you may be tempted to rub its bark up the wrong way, it is just a "thing" -- that happens to have sexual organs. As we may, or may not, learn from the history of suppositories, "sexual organs" ought be treated with a certain intelligence. Why are you even asking this lol?

Comment: How do you know that a dog cannot give consent in the same way that a tree cannot? Please explain your reasoning here.

Comment: how is a tree going to agree to have sex with you @curiousdannii

Comment: I never said any such thing. This is your answer, so it's your responsibility to make your case.

Comment: it's an argument from analogy @curiousdannii ["it's just a 'thing' -- that happens to have sexual organs"]